# Pass a parent class as a parameter to a function

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

This is a basic PHP question, and somehow I couldn't find any information about it.

So what I'm trying to do is to pass a parent class to a function so all of its children class can be passed too.

Is there anyway to do it?

```
function transform(Fruit $fruit){}

transform($orange)
transform($apple)
```

---

Update :

Looks like I need to show the situation more.

So what I have is a transformer parent

```
class ResourceTransformer{
    public function transform(ResourceModel $model){}
}
```

And its child

```
class ColorTransformer extends ResourceTransformer{}
```

Now what I want to do is passing ColorModel, a child of ResourceModel to ColorTransformer.

```
class ColorModel extends ResourceModel{}
```

when I'm doing that it throws an error like this:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\\Modules\\Product\\Transformer\\ResourcesTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\\Modules\\Product\\Models\\ResourceModel, instance of App\\Modules\\Product\\Models\\ColorModel given.
```

So basically, ColorTransformer can't accept ColorModel and only accept ResourceModel, yet ColorModel is a child of ResourceModel. Might be some of you can give me more enlightement.

Comment: Pass class name to function

Comment: You just did it in your example? What is the problem with your example?

Comment: Right now, I can only throw the child instance, and nothing else.

Comment: Can you show us the lines from your code when you declare namespaces and uses? Is every your clasess place in one file or different?

Comment: It's working idea: https://3v4l.org/6gLUc . Look for a typo.

Comment: But, it seems, that you are trying to break LSP in your code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @zajonc its in different file

Comment: @sectus can you enlightment me about this LSP things, i only try LSD unfortunately

Comment: @DimasSatrio and what about your namespaces and uses in files? Look at sectus working idea - it's a good example how should it work.

Comment: @zajonc no problem with the namespace and uses, it just didnt work with the ColorModel even thought its extension from ResourceModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this code to check your problem

```
class ResourceModel { }

class ResourceTransformer
{
    public function transform(ResourceModel $model)
    {
        var_dump($model);
    }
}

class ColorTransformer extends ResourceTransformer { }

class ColorModel extends ResourceModel { }

$transformer = new ColorTransformer();
$model = new ColorModel();

$transformer->transform($model);
```

and i've got correct result

> object(ColorModel)#2 (0) { }

If this is not working in your case then it's look like the class `ResourceModel` form this part of your code

```
class ResourceTransformer{
    public function transform(ResourceModel $model){}
}
```

is not the same that in this part

```
class ColorModel extends ResourceModel{}
```

You told in comment that the problem is only with the `ColorModel` but your information about error tell us that namespaces for `ResourceModel` and `ColorModel` are the same so I think the problem is with your `ResourceTransformer` class definition - do you have this code somewhere in top of your file with this definition?

```
use App\Modules\Product\Models\ResourceModel;
```

If you don't then do you have an another declaration of the `ResourceModel` class somewhere in your file with `ResourceTransformer` class definition?

The other thing I see in your question is the difference between this part of your code

```
class ResourceTransformer{
    public function transform(ResourceModel $model){}
}
```

and class name in your error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Modules\Product\Transformer\ResourcesTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\Modules\Product\Models\ResourceModel, instance of App\Modules\Product\Models\ColorModel given.

Look that in error you have a class `ResourcesTransformer` and you tell us that this class is named `ResourceTransformer`. If this difference is ok then your problem should be placed in file with declaration of the `ResourcesTransformer` class.

Comment: this is correct, thank you there are 2 different ResourceModel definition, I screwed it up.

The transformer is correct :)

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this and didn't realize it until after it locked. This is a very comprehensive response; apologies.

Comment: @ErikJ.Olson No problem, it happens, thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass name of class as a string and dinamically instantiate it:

```
function transform($name_of_class){
...
new $name_of_class;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cant pass any other information except the child instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example please;

```
<?php
// function transform(Fruit $fruit){ //or
function transform($fruit){
    print_r($fruit);
}

class Fruit{
    public $name = null;
    function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

transform(new Fruit('Apple')); // result: Fruit Object ( [name] => Apple )
echo '<br />';
$orange = new Fruit('Orange');
transform($orange); // result: Fruit Object ( [name] => Orange )
```